# "heroku run rake assets:clean" doesn't clean anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I execute

```
$ heroku run rake assets:clean
Running `rake assets:clean` attached to terminal... up, run.2
/usr/local/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rm -rf /app/public/assets
```

But it doesn't look like it is working due I can access to the assets by http request and also if I open a *heroku console* I can see the files:

```
$ heroku run console
irb(main):013:0> Dir.glob "./public/assets/*"
=> ["./public/assets/img", "./public/assets/application.js.gz", "./public/assets/application.js", "./public/assets/rails.png", "./public/assets/manifest.yml", "./public/assets/application.css", "./public/assets/assets", "./public/assets/application.css.gz"]
```

I need to remove the assets because they are producing conflicts with my new configuration.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?  I have an app that seems to have assets that aren't getting updated on subsequent pushes.  If I spin up a new instance of Cedar, the server uses the correct assets.

Comment: @MichaelPell I didn't find any solution for this, sorry.

Comment: I too have assets *lodged* in my Heroku `public/assets` directory which I would dearly like to remove. Sadly, `assets:clean` does not take care of it. If anyone else has a solution other than spinning up a new instance, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what `public/assets`. I now believe that the `asset_sync` gem compiles the assets into `public/assets` and then syncs the results to S3 which means the `public/assets` directory *SHOULD* be filled with the assets. I was originally thinking that they shouldn't be there if we're using the `asset_sync` gem.

Comment: Notice that Heroku is removing `/app/public/assets`, not `/public/assets`. It's looking at the wrong assets directory. I'm not sure yet how to fix this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The rake assets:clean functionality has been replaced with

```
rake assets:clobber
```

in the latest version of Rails.

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Can someone confirm this is working, so I can accept the answer, I can't test it right now.

Comment: It did not work for me. Heroku reported `Don't know how to build task 'assets:clobber'`

Comment: Are you using Rails 4.0?

Comment: FWIW I just successfully ran `bundle exec rake assets:clobber` in both Rails 4.0 and Rails 4.1. You can see the command described in the Sprockets docs I link to in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do:

```
heroku repo:purge_cache
```

and wait a bit. `rake assets:clobber` did not work for me, even though it printed:

```
INFO -- : Removed /app/public/assets
rm -rf /app/tmp/cache/assets]
```

if you run the heroku command and get:

```
 !    `repo:purge_cache` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

install the command in your heroku toolbelt with:

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
```

and rerun.