# How to reset Heroku Rails4 asset pipeline cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

According to Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline):

> Heroku now caches 50mb worth of tmp/cache/assets which is a cache
>   directory for the asset pipeline to store intermediate files. This
>   means that future asset compilations will be faster due to not having
>   to recalculate these files.

My question is how do I manually reset or delete this cache so that all of my assets have to be precompiled again? I tried `heroku run console` and `Rails.cache.clear` but it did not work. The reason I want to reset the cache is I have changed the `config.action_controller.asset_host` in my `production.rb` file but Heroku is not picking up on the change because of the cache.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hopefully this helps.  To get changes to **Heroku** in development I run `rake assets:clean` and then `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace` before **committing** and pushing to **Heroku**

Comment: This worked thanks. Instead of running `rake assets:clean` I ran `rake assets:clobber` as I read that `rake assets:clean` has been replaced with `rake assets:clobber` for Rail 4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/15355381/1276696

Comment: ...the key being "before committing and pushing to Heroku". Don't run "rake assets:precompile on Heroku, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 16):

To purge Heroku's asset cache, you need the [Heroku Repo plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo) to the Heroku toolbelt. Install that, then use the command

```
heroku repo:purge_cache
```

Deploy after purging the cache.

Comment: This takes a minute or two to try out and probably does everything the other answers do and more. Fixed everything for me after trying other solutions forever, thank you

Comment: 'heroku run rake assets:clobber ...'  did NOT work for me.  This did.  The "takes a minute or two" is key.

Comment: I was getting
'remote:        LoadError: cannot load such file -- coffee_script'
errors during a heroku push/precompile because some coffee file was cached somewhere on heroku. This is the only cache purge that worked to clear that up. (ie assets:clobber didnt fix it)

Answer (score 4):

For cleaning assets, run:

> rake assets:clobber

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't work. It took 6 seconds to precompile on a push before I did the clobber and still 6 seconds after and my files still hadn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, then i realized I forgot to configure to serve static assets on the production env, inside config/enviroments/production.rb

```
config. serve_static_files = true
```

Comment: **serve_static_assets** is **deprecated** in Rails 4.2. It changed to **config.serve_static_files**

Answer (score 1):

As [this Stack Overflow answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345530/1633753), `config.assets.version` exists for this purpose.

Most likely, you'll find it in config/application.rb or config/initializers/assets.rb.  Change it to any value you want to break the cache next time you deploy to any environment.